# Access outer $index when ng-repeat are nested in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Consider the following nested `ng-repeat` directives:

```html
  <tr ng-repeat="r in SomeExpr1">
    <td ng-repeat="c in SomeExpr2">
      <p>c index is {{$index}}, r index is {{???}}</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

How can I access the `$index` of the outer `ng-repeat` (i.e., the one in the parent scope that is hidden by the inner `ng-repeat` scope `$index`)?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in AngularDart `1.0.0`? Using `$parent` results in a `NoSuchMethodError` as it is trying to find an instance getter in the component.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As @Randal Schwartz pointed out in [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/128) `$parent` does the trick.

```dart
<div ng-controller='demo-ctrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="row in ctrl.matrix">
    <div ng-repeat="column in row">
      <span>outer: {{$parent.$index}} inner: {{$index}}</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can someone check if this still works? $parent is returning null for me.

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: angular 0.10.0                .

Answer (score 5):

You need `ng-init` from Angular.js.  Sadly, that hasn't been ported yet, but it would look like this if it worked:

```js
<script>
  function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']];
  }
</script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="innerList in list" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    <div ng-repeat="value in innerList" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
       <span class="example-init">list[ {{outerIndex}} ][ {{innerIndex}} ] = {{value}};</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(via http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: ng-init is not planned https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/128 but it should be easy to add a custom directive that stores this value to make it reusable in the inner repeat

Comment: Well, I withdraw my request for ng-init, even though it makes demos a bit easier. :)  Happy to just put my init in my controller, and use $parent to get to the next-outer $index.  Case CLOSED.

Comment: I really don't know about angular.dart but, in plain angular :P you should really use $parent.$index as it's not really safe. The example @RandalSchwartz its safer... If you add an ng-if inside the loop, you get the $index messed, check:
http://plnkr.co/52oIhLfeXXI9ZAynTuAJ